# Unable to match and replace " and ' characters in a text file

Tags: python, replace, double-quotes

Hello: I have a text file where the double- and single-quote characters cannot be matched and replaced (Python 3.5.2).  Below is a sample word copied and pasted.

```
>>> line_copied_pasted = 'gilingan.”'
>>> line_copied_pasted.replace('"','')
'gilingan.”'
```

When the string is manually entered, matching succeeds:

```
>>> line_manually_entered = 'gilingan."'
>>> line_manually_entered
'gilingan."'
>>> line_manually_entered.replace('"','')
'gilingan.'
```

The file is UTF-16 encoded, I think. Any help to fix the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Well `”` and `"` are different characters.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have it figured out. Since it both `”` and `"` are different, it does not make sense to try replacing first while comparing with the latter.

Just do :

```
line_copied_pasted.replace('”','')
```

Comment: Thanks, kvorobiev and Kaushik NP. That did it!

Answer (score 1):

In copied text `”`(right double quotation mark) and `"`(quotation mark) are different characters. You could check their codes [here](https://unicodelookup.com/#"/1).